# Variables runtime error doubts solve it Runtim

Tags: java, variables, compiler-errors, runtime, jaxb2-basics

I have started learning java and there is this one line which I am not getting clearly that -

Variables are interpreted at runtime whereas values/constants at compile time ??

Can anyone explain this with suitable code..

Answer (score 0):

A Compile-time Constant: a primitive type or String, declared final, initialized within its declaration, and with a constant expression.
Example:

```
public final int maximumLoginAttempts = 5;
```

A Runtime Constant: value cannot change while the program is running. However, each time when we run the application, it can have a different value:
Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Console console = System.console();
    final String input = console.readLine();
    console.writer().println(input);
}
```